# from hql to criteria query (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

i have the following hql query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select b.id from Buyer b, User u where  b.user=u.id");
```

where it retrieves a list of id buyers having user id, i am joining between two tables (Buyer and User) and the Buyer table has foreign key to the id User table

i don't know how to convert this to criteria
i tried this

```
Criteria query2 = session.createCriteria(Buyer.class).createCriteria("user").add(Restrictions.like("id", "user.id"));
```

but it is not working
any help?

Comment: session.createCriteria(Buyer.class).createAlias("user", "user", Criteria.INNER_JOIN).setProjection(Projections.property("id"))

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked
but i want to ask a question please
why did you write createAlias("user", "user") like this
shouldn't it be createAlias("User", "user") where the first parameter is the class name and the second parameter is the alias for that class?

Comment: The first parameter is the association path, i.e. the property that maps the foreign key.